# How do you Suppress Core File Modification Notices?

Tags: notification

Is it possible to disable the core file modification modification notices/alerts in the control panel?

When we commit updates into version control, the next page load in the CP on our staging server will get the "One or more core files have been altered," and whatever action a user was doing in the control panel (writing an entry, editing a setting, etc.) will be lost.

Comment: if it really does the latter, e.g. break workflow, then maybe you could file a bug report.

Comment: Good point; I suppose breaking the workflow as you describe is a genuine bug.

Comment: Bug Report sent: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20031

Comment: EL has accepted as bug: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20031

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying issue here was caused by [an ExpressionEngine bug that was corrected in version 2.8.0](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20031).